# Same Colors to Match Two Contour Plots

Tags: plotting, color

I have two contour plots:

```
c1 = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  FrameTicks -> None]
c2 = ContourPlot[10*Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  FrameTicks -> None]
```

I want to be able to compare them not only in terms of numbers but also in terms of colors. So same value -> same color.

How can I make sure that the colors between the two contour plots match ? Also, they should have one unique legend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the narrowest range that covers the range of both plots and use it as color function range in both plots:

```
range = MapThread[# @ #2 &, {{Min, Max}, Transpose @
 (Through[{MinValue, MaxValue}[{#, 0 <= x <= 4 Pi,  0 <= y <= 4 Pi}, {x, y}, Reals]] & /@ 
   {Cos[x] + Cos[y], 10 Cos[x] + Cos[y]})}]
{c1, c2} =  ContourPlot[#, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  FrameTicks -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic,ImageSize -> 300,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", range}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ 
   {Cos[x] + Cos[y], 10 Cos[x] + Cos[y]};

Row[{c1, c2}]
```

[image]

To use the default color function with the new color range change `"Rainbow"` above to `"M10DefaultDensityGradient"` to get:

[image]

Comment: Nice ! Thanks a lot !!