# How can I get the contour shading in two contour plots to correspond?

Tags: plotting

[Link to code.](https://pastebin.com/vKkhfqTv)

When I ploted the first contour map shown below, I found `Z = 1` is corresponding to Canary yellow. But when I ploted another contour map, the same value corresponds to Goose yellow.

How can I solve this problem?

Contour plot 1

[image: contour plot 1]

Contour plot 2

[image: contour plot 2]

[image: my attempt]
[image: my attempt]

Comment: Can you post the data needed to reproduce your plots? If they are too big, please put them in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and link to it here.

Comment: I am novice,I don't understand how put the data in Pastebin.Sorry.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: There is editing help available right on the page where you enter your question. As soon a you put your mouse cursor into the text entry box, a help message appears to the right of entry box. At the bottom of the message there are three links giving further help. The first one will take you to a page giving details on the markdown formatting we use on this site. Another good way to learn is simply to click on the edit button at the bottom of any well-formatted question. This will show you the formatting commands that were used.

Comment: Thank your for your reminding

Comment: related [Scale coloring of ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64366/125) and [Same Colors to Match Two Contour Plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174338/125)

Comment: Thank you for your instructions.@kglr